# Mysql don't use index while self joining a table with indexed criteria

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.6

When self joining a table with criteria as indexed column, mysql goes for full table scan. By changing the join order , we can able to use index .

Table schema for EmployeeDetails

```
EmployeeDetails | CREATE TABLE `EmployeeDetails` (
  `CompanyId` bigint(19) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `EmployeeId` bigint(19) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ParentEmployeeId` bigint(19) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EmployeeId`),
  KEY `EmployeeDetails_FK1_IDX` (`CompanyId`),
  KEY `EmployeeDetails_FK2_IDX` (`ParentEmployeeId`),
  CONSTRAINT `EmployeeDetails_FK1` FOREIGN KEY (`CompanyId`) REFERENCES `CompanyDetails` (`CompanyId`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `EmployeeDetails_FK2` FOREIGN KEY (`ParentEmployeeId`) REFERENCES `EmployeeDetails` (`EmployeeId`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Table schema for CompanyDetails

```
| CompanyDetails | CREATE TABLE `CompanyDetails` (
  `CompanyId` bigint(19) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NAME` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DESCRIPTION` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CompanyId`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
|
```

First query - first select will scan all records in EmployeeDetails table and do self joining (won't use index KEY EmployeeDetails_FK1_IDX (CompanyId) which is used in criteria)

```
mysql> select * from EmployeeDetails INNER JOIN `EmployeeDetails` `t1` ON `EmployeeDetails`.`EmployeeId`=`t1`.`ParentEmployeeId` where `EmployeeDetails`.`CompanyId` IN(123);
Empty set (0.10 sec)

mysql> explain select * from EmployeeDetails INNER JOIN `EmployeeDetails` `t1` ON `EmployeeDetails`.`EmployeeId`=`t1`.`ParentEmployeeId` where `EmployeeDetails`.`CompanyId` IN(123)\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t1
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: EmployeeDetails_FK2_IDX
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 7999
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: EmployeeDetails
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,EmployeeDetails_FK1_IDX
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: db.t1.ParentEmployeeId
         rows: 1
     filtered: 5.00
        Extra: Using where
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

Second query - first select records from EmployeeDetails using EmployeeDetails_FK1_IDX(CompanyId`) index and scan only records matching the criteria and do self joining

```
mysql> select * from EmployeeDetails INNER JOIN `EmployeeDetails` `t1` ON `t1`.`EmployeeId`=`EmployeeDetails`.`ParentEmployeeId` where `EmployeeDetails`.`CompanyId` IN(123);
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select * from EmployeeDetails INNER JOIN `EmployeeDetails` `t1` ON `t1`.`EmployeeId`=`EmployeeDetails`.`ParentEmployeeId` where `EmployeeDetails`.`CompanyId` IN(123)\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: EmployeeDetails
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: EmployeeDetails_FK1_IDX,EmployeeDetails_FK2_IDX
          key: EmployeeDetails_FK1_IDX
      key_len: 8
          ref: const
         rows: 54
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t1
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: db.EmployeeDetails.ParentEmployeeId
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it can be seen in the EXPLAIN, "EmployeeDetails_FK2_IDX" is listed as a possible key. If MySQL optimizer doesn't use it, it's just that it would not reduce the query time.

Try to populate table with data (I checked it and it works as is) and you should see that MySQL optimizer will use an index for the join without looking their orders. Because orders of joins do not have any affect on MySQL optimizer algorithms.

Also check **[STRAIGHT_JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)**

Comment: My question is: In first query, why table t1 is selected first?. If EmployeeDetails is selected first then EmployeeDetails_FK1_IDX can be used.
That is actually done in second query (FYI I am not only changing the join order, i changed join criteria from EmployeeDetails`.`EmployeeId`=`t1`.`ParentEmployeeId` to `t1`.`EmployeeId`=`EmployeeDetails`.`ParentEmployeeId`.
But both gives same resultset.

Comment: I saw the order change but again it does not have any affect on MySQL optimizer algorithms while using proper indexing. So, not using index on first query does not related with the order, it is related with data size and optimizer's choice. Explain result also shows that, index correctly find and it can be used if it helps. For your question at my answer: The tables are listed in the output in the order that MySQL would read them while processing the query. If it does not convince you, please update your post with this question.

Comment: So how the optimizer chooses which table is selected first(the order in which the table selected). In my case both tables are same. In first query, the optimizer chooses t1 as first table and there is no criteria for table t1 and possible key for t1 is EmployeeDetails_FK2_IDX. But optimizer chooses for full table scan because it might be better than using EmployeeDetails_FK2_IDX. That is fine.
But if the optimizer chooses the EmployeeDetails as first select, then it can use EmployeeDetails_FK1_IDX.
FYI my use case is to get all details of EmployeeDetails for a given CompanyDetails.CompanyId.

Comment: Using index does not related the order of query selection. In your case, whatever chosen for the first selection, if index is available and useful optimizer will use it. Did you try to populate table and looking the index usage? Can you explain that what did you intent to get all detail of  EmployeeDetails? with its parents data?

Comment: Maybe STRAIGHT_JOIN can helps you. Check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html